# Spiral of death after kernal update 4.4.8-v7+: How to restore Kernel with no internet connection?

Tags: kernel, boot-issues

I updated my raspberry pi to the latest kernel 4.4.8-v7+ using rpi-update...

After updating everything started to go downhill:lxpanel would crash loop on start up and wireless adapter was not working (configured as an host).
I changed boot to command line in raspi-config, couldn't get lxpanel to work properly, but aside from that was ok. I then changed it back to start in xterminal but everything went real bad after: my boot now stops at nonblocking pool is initialized...

If I press enter I can login, but the host is now (none) and I get tons of error Function not implemented and have no networking (ifconfig just through a function not implemented..)

Is it possible to revert kernel? Or at this point just give up and restart from fresh?

Comment: In the end I  just reinstalled everything on a fresh install, started with the kernel update and everything else was working ok,. just bad luck and 6h wasted ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used `rpi-update`, there should be a folder on the top level named `/boot.bak`. That's the kernel backup that the updater makes before updating.

Simply move/rename/remove the contents `/boot` then copy/move the contents of `/boot.bak` to `/boot` and you should be good to go.

Some commands to get you started:

```
sudo rm -rf /boot/*              # Remove the current boot stuff
sudo cp -rf /boot.bak/* /boot    # Copy the backed-up boot files to /boot
```

Comment: I can't use sudo: I get the message unable to resolve host (none), any work around? I'll try to mount the card on a linux pc to do the copy in the meantime.

Comment: Never mind last post: I booted from another SD card and copied the file from the boot.bak folder. It didn't fix my boot problem though. At least I am able to get the files off the other SD card.. I think it might be corrupt as I tried to back it up and it failed.